# Are these bugs in lit-html?

Tags: lit-html

In lit-html 1.0.0-rc.2, I have the following template, which does not work correctly. So, I suppose I'm doing something wrong. Or is this just a bug in lit-html?

```js
import { html } from './node_modules/lit-html/lit-html.js';
import css from './css.js';

export default function template(c) {
  console.log('props', c.text, c.selected, c.checkbox, c.radioButton);
  const changeText = c.changeText.bind(c);
  return html`
    ${css()}
    <form>
      <div>input cannot be updated programatically</div>
      <input type="text" value="${c.text}" @input="${changeText}"/>

      <div>select cannot be set/changed programatically</div>
      <select @change="${ev => {c.selected = ev.currentTarget.value; console.log('value set to', ev.currentTarget.value)}}">
        <option value="" ?selected="${c.selcted === ''}">Select</option>
        <option value="1" ?selected="${c.selcted === '1'}">1</option>
        <option value="2" ?selected="${c.selcted === '2'}">2</option>
        <option value="3" ?selected="${c.selcted === '3'}">3</option>
        <option value="4" ?selected="${c.selcted === '4'}">4</option>
      </select>
      <div>checkbox cannot be updated programatically</div>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        @change="${(ev) => {c.checkbox = ev.currentTarget.value; console.log('checkbox value:', ev.currentTarget.value)}}"
        ?checked="${c.checkbox === 'on'}"
      />
      <div>radio buttons cannot be updated programatically</div>
      <input
        name="radio"
        type="radio"
        value="1"
        @change="${ev => {c.radioButton = '1'; console.log('radio button value: ', ev.currentTarget.value)}}"
        ?checked="${c.radioButton === '1'}"/>
      <label>1</label>
      <input
        name="radio"
        type="radio"
        value="2"
        @change="${ev => {c.radioButton = '2'; console.log('radio button value: ', ev.currentTarget.value)}}"
        ?checked="${c.radioButton === '2'}"/>
      <label>2</label>
      <input
        name="radio"
        type="radio"
        value="3"
        @change="${ev => {c.radioButton = '3'; console.log('radio button value: ', ev.currentTarget.value)}}"
        ?checked="${c.radioButton === '3'}"/>
      <label>3</label>
    </form>
  `;
}
```

It is populated/controlled by the following web component:

```js
import { render } from './node_modules/lit-html/lit-html.js';
import template from './template.js';

class MyForm extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
    this.text = 'foo';
    this.selected = '2';
    this.checkbox = 'on';
    this.radioButton = '1';
  }

  attributeChangedCallback(name, oVal, nVal) {

  }

  connectedCallback() {
    this.render();
    setInterval(() => {
      this.text = 'foobar';
      this.selected = '3';
      this.checkbox = 'off';
      this.radioButton = '2';
      this.render();
    }, 2000);
  }

  disconnectedCallback() {

  }

  changeText(ev) {
    const { value } = ev.currentTarget;
    this.text = value;
    this.render();
  }

  render() {
    render(template(this), this.shadowRoot);
  }

  static get observedAttributes() {
    return ['']
  }
}
customElements.get('my-form') || customElements.define('my-form', MyForm);

export { MyForm }
```

Note the web component attempts to set the value of various inputs on first render. Thereafter, it attempts to set them again using setInterval. setInterval is used solely to show how the web component is attempting to update the template.

In the case of the select, an option cannot be set programatically. And in the case of each of the other input elements, once selected in the UI cannot be updated programatically.

Comment: are you still having this problem? can you extract what goes wrong e.g. what it does and what it should do... I'm a little lost here

Comment: The dom of the WebComponent will be initialized after the constructor ran so setting a value of an child in constructor wont work because there is no child to give the value to.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a bug in Lit, though you're using it in quite a unique way.

In the case of your `<select>` the problem is that you're setting `c.selected` but then checking `c.selcted` in each `<option>`.